# difference between two vectors and an unknown

Tags: vectors

can't even work out where to start with this question, looked online at differences between vectors, found the difference between **p** & **q** to be 6root2. Any help very much appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP1m6.png)

[image]

Comment: Hint: what exactly does the condition $d(p,x)=d(q,x)$ mean? Literally, it says "the distance between p and x equals the distance between q and x." What does this tell you about the vector $x$? Surely you can think of such a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the mipoint of the two vectors  $
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc} 
3  \\
1 \\
-3 \\ 
\end{array} \right).
$

Comment: ok thank you, i think the 0 after the x just threw me off track and confused me, glad it's got such a simple solution